# android studio, how to change the logCat to old style for searching against the message content

Tags: android-studio

Just installed the current AndroidStudio Griaffe.

In the code there are logs made with some special "mark" so that it has been able to search/search against it in logCat's search box.

But with the new AndroidStudio Giraffe it seems does not work .

For example, in the code a log is made with:

```
Log.e(TAG, "SPECIAL_MARK getInstance(), ret: $it")
```

No result when put in message:SPECIAL_MARK.

Is there a way to switch back to old logCat style with AS Giraffe?

[image]

Comment: I think you should search for "TAG" not for second part of `Log`

Comment: Have you tried putting in plain text "SPECIAL_MARK" in the filter window? Without "message:" tag?